# Problem after upgrading Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04, after I got a notification about it. All the installation went well but after restart now, when I go to the Ubuntu option from grub, it shows only a purple screen and nothing happens after that. I also have Windows 8 installed in my laptop, but hope that should not be a problem, as it worked well with ubuntu 13.10.

Please help me to fix this problem, or at least to get back to my previous ubuntu I had.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) summs up quite coherently what to do in case of purple screen after Ubuntu boot.

You have to edit the ubuntu option in grub (Pres `e` on the option) and add kernel parameter `nomodeset` after or instead of the `quiet splash` parameter.
The screen will look odd and you will not have correct screen resolution etc, but it should run and you should be able to install correct video drivers.

What can sometimes help is use `acpi_osi=Linux` instead of `nomodeset`. This can fix it, but to make the fix permanent you have to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

After saving the edit run `sudo update-grub`

I would recommend though to check for the video drivers first.